# SpringBeanFactory ApplicationContext returns null and org.apache.commons.logging.LogConfigurationException: java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, spring, apache, hibernate

I have 3 projects:
1st contains: jars
2nd contains: hibernate entities, dao etc.
3rd contains: application to create tables using hibernate entities using 2nd project.
There is no classpath or any library error. but when I run the application, it gives exception (see stacktrace below):

```
    org.apache.commons.logging.LogConfigurationException: java.lang.NullPointerException (Caused by java.lang.NullPointerException) (Caused by org.apache.commons.logging.LogConfigurationException: java.lang.NullPointerException (Caused by java.lang.NullPointerException))
    org.apache.commons.logging.LogConfigurationException: org.apache.commons.logging.LogConfigurationException: java.lang.NullPointerException (Caused by java.lang.NullPointerException) (Caused by org.apache.commons.logging.LogConfigurationException: java.lang.NullPointerException (Caused by java.lang.NullPointerException)) at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.newInstance(LogFactoryImpl.java:543)
     at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.getInstance(LogFactoryImpl.java:235) at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.getInstance(LogFactoryImpl.java:209) at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:351) at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.<init>(AbstractApplicationContext.java:161)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.<init>(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:90) at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableConfigApplicationContext.<init>(AbstractRefreshableConfigApplicationContext.java:59)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.<init>(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:61) at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:136)
        at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83) at org.cpc.erp.common.beans.SpringBeanFactory.<init>(SpringBeanFactory.java:31)
        at org.cpc.erp.common.beans.SpringBeanFactory.getInstance(SpringBeanFactory.java:40) at org.cpc.erp.gui.PatchNewComponentsAddition$4.run(PatchNewComponentsAddition.java:145)
    Caused by: org.apache.commons.logging.LogConfigurationException: java.lang.NullPointerException (Caused by java.lang.NullPointerException) at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.getLogConstructor(LogFactoryImpl.java:397)
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.getLogConstructor(LogFactoryImpl.java:374)
... 13 more
```

Here is SpringBeanFactory class:

```
    private SpringBeanFactory() {
    private final String CONFIGURATION_XML = "META-INF/applicationContext.xml";
      try {
          context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(CONFIGURATION_XML);
          setEnvironment(context.getEnvironment());
          } catch (Exception e) {
          logger.log(Level.ERROR, e.getMessage(), e);
       }
     }
```

I debugged application, after this line:
         context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(CONFIGURATION_XML);
it throws exception.
Kindly help me out I am stuck.
Thanks.

Comment: It can't find your XML

Comment: I tried different strings like 'META-INF/applicationContext.xml', 'applicationContext.xml', '/src/META-INF/applicationContext.xml' but still same error.

Comment: Place the applicationContext.xml in the src dir and use CONFIGURATION_XML = "applicationContext.xml"

Comment: still the same error.

Comment: Check generated classes whether the xml exists there.

Comment: You mean in 'bin' folder, then yes.
bin\META-INF\applicationContext.xml

Comment: META-INF is not part of classpath so content can't be accessed. Move the xml out of the META-INF to classpath root -> folder where classes exist